# How to create a interactive 2D canvas in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, layout

I'd like to create a 2D canvas or board populated with various Text View objects as well as lines connecting those views.

[image]

I'd like to be able to add and remove objects dynamically.

Is there a way to do this type of interactive layout using SwiftUI efficiently? I welcome any pointers or examples helping me to find the right foundation for this type of interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DragGesture()` on custom textviews to create something like this.

Here's a simple implementation in SwiftUI for what you're looking for.

Demo link: https://www.trace.zip/c/9c29fc1a-d3c6-4ac4-8368-33d9b3be0ae6

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct DraggableTextView: View {
    @State private var dragOffset1: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var dragOffset2: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var dragOffset3: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Path { path in
                let startPoint = CGPoint(x: dragOffset1.width + 250, y: dragOffset1.height + 400)
                let endPoint = CGPoint(x: dragOffset2.width + 250, y: dragOffset2.height + 400)
                path.move(to: startPoint)
                path.addLine(to: endPoint)
                
                let secondEndPoint = CGPoint(x: dragOffset3.width + 250, y: dragOffset3.height + 400)
                path.move(to: endPoint)
                path.addLine(to: secondEndPoint)
            }
            .stroke(Color.green, lineWidth: 3)
            
            DraggableBox(title: "Title 1", label: "Label 1", color: .blue, offset: $dragOffset1)
            DraggableBox(title: "Title 2", label: "Label 2", color: .red, offset: $dragOffset2)
            DraggableBox(title: "Title 3", label: "Label 3", color: .purple, offset: $dragOffset3)
        }
    }
}

struct DraggableBox: View {
    var title: String
    var label: String
    var color: Color
    @Binding var offset: CGSize
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            
            Text(label)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .padding(10)
        .background(color)
        .cornerRadius(8)
        .offset(offset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    self.offset = gesture.translation
                }
        )
        
    }
}

struct LineView: Shape {
    var start: CGPoint
    var end: CGPoint

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: start)
        path.addLine(to: end)
        return path
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        DraggableTextView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Link to demo:
https://www.trace.zip/c/9c29fc1a-d3c6-4ac4-8368-33d9b3be0ae6